# How to continuously read from the serial port in Matlab?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, serial-port

This is my code:

```
serialPort = 'COM3';
s = serial(serialPort,'BaudRate',9600);    
if (s.Status == 'closed')       
    s.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'byte';
    s.BytesAvailableFcnCount = 200;
    s.BytesAvailableFcn = @Serial_OnDataReceived;

    fopen(s);
end
```

This is the CallBack function

```
function Serial_OnDataReceived(obj,event)
global s;
global i;
global endCheck;
global yVals;
global xVals;

if (s.Status == 'open')
    while s.BytesAvailable > 0 && endCheck ~= '1',
        data = str2num(fgetl(s));
        dlmwrite ('SensorsReading.csv', data, '-append');

        yVals = circshift(yVals,-1);
        yVals(end) = data(3);

        xVals = circshift(xVals,-1);
        i = i + 0.0125;
        xVals(end) = i;
    end

    figure(1);
    plot(xVals,yVals);

end
```

end

Right after the `FOPEN` function, I get this Warning:

> The BytesAvailableFcn is being disabled. To enable the callback property
>   either connect to the hardware with FOPEN or set the BytesAvailableFcn property.

Does the logic that happens in the callback function `Serial_OnDataReceived` run on a different thread?

Is there a way to pass parameters to the function? I want to modify an array in the main script from the callback function, which is in a different file. What's the best way to do so?
I am also trying to plot the values when they're updated to show some kind of dynamic animation.

Comment: Matlab is single-threaded. I assume something is wrong with your callback function. Wrong number of parameters or similar, could you provide the code?

Comment: ^added. Also added a plot question

Comment: I was unable to run your code as I don't have any possibility to set up a serial port, but I am really sure your Function causes errors. At least the `s.Status == 'open'` throws a dimension mismatch when status is `closed'`. Use `strcmpi`. With all the global vars it's hard to tell if there are more issues. Try setting a breakpoint and debug your callback function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what is generating the warning, but to answer your other question (how to pass parameter to the callback and how to update the plot), a better way to go would be to prepare your plot outside of the callback, then pass the handle to the callback for update only.

```
nPointsInFigure = 10 ;  %// number of "sliding points" in your figure
step = 0.0125 ;         %// X points spacing
xVals = linspace(-(nPointsInFigure-1)*step,0,nPointsInFigure) ; %// prepare empty data for the plot
yVals = NaN(nPointsInFigure,1) ;

figure(1) ;
hp = plot( xVals , yVals ) ; %// Generate the plot (with empty data) it will be passed to the callback.

serialPort = 'COM3';
s = serial(serialPort,'BaudRate',9600);  
if (s.Status == 'closed')       
    s.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'byte';
    s.BytesAvailableFcnCount = 200;
    s.BytesAvailableFcn = {@Serial_OnDataReceived,hp,step} ; %// note how the parameters are passed to the callback 
    fopen(s);
end
```

Your callback will become:

```
function Serial_OnDataReceived(obj,event,hp,step)

global endCheck; %// I don't know how you use that so I could not get rid of it.

xVals = get(hp,'XData') ; %// retrieve the X values from the plot
yVals = get(hp,'YData') ; %// retrieve the Y values from the plot

while obj.BytesAvailable > 0 && endCheck ~= '1',
    data = str2num(fgetl(s));
    dlmwrite ('SensorsReading.csv', data, '-append');

    yVals = circshift(yVals,-1);
    yVals(end) = data(3);

    xVals = circshift(xVals,-1);
    xVals(end) = xVals(end-1) + step ;
end

set( hp , 'XData',xVals , 'YData',yVals ) ; %// update the plot with the new values
```

Also note: (1) You don't need to check for the state open/close of the serial port within the callback function. If the event was triggered it means the port was open. (2) you don't need to declare `s` as global, the `obj` parameter is actually the serial object itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the suggestion from Hoki does not work, try using a timer.

```
% The following line is useful for debugging 
mytimerCallback = @(~, ~) disp('Caught error For Tenzo Timer');

if isempty(timerXbee)
     timerXbee = timer('ExecutionMode','FixedRate','Period',0.1,...
                    'TimerFcn',{@storeDataFromSerial},'ErrorFcn', mytimerCallback);
     try
         start(timerXbee);  
     catch
         disp('Timer Xbee');
         disp '******** InstrumentSubscription ERROR *********'
         disp (exception.message);
         disp '***********************************************'
     end
end

% If you are using a polling approach, request data

sendRequest(cmd);
connectionRequested = true;
```

Then implement the timer function that will be called every period

```
function storeDataFromSerial(~,~,~)
    while (get(xbee, 'BytesAvailable')~=0)
        serialProtocol();                
    end
end
```

When you want to disconnect the device and close the communication don't forget to stop the timer with

```
stop(timerXbee)
```